# 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ruby, sass

Am trying to install Sass on my PC.I have installed Ruby and when opening the CMD and typing gem install sass am getting error

> While executing gem ... (Errno::ENETRESET)
>       The connection has been broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failur
>   e while the operation was in progress. - recvfrom(2)

I have installed Koala App for Sass but there also am getting error

> 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Any clues why please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on windows so you might be have an issue because of firewall Closes ruby connection when ruby need a connection to install Gems. You can go to this link http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/20561-gem-installation-issues-errnoenetreset for more information

Comment: I have disabled my Antivirus.It is NOD32 but again i am getting that same error.Any other ideas?

Comment: @AnahitDEV Are you getting this issue on installing any gem or is it specific with sass

Comment: it is something wring related to GEM generally

Comment: Even when am checking the Gem verion i see the result of its version

Comment: Any ideas @punitcse? I have tried many many things but no luck!what i could do?i only need to use sass

Comment: @AnahitDEV it is related with the network configurations.Please check http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/20546-occurring-errors-errnoenetreset-while-installing-rails-gem.
Can you check it on some other network.

Comment: i cant check it on other network.How i could do that?but connection why could cause such issues?